Posting to api truncates the last part of the base64 string on large files over 5mb
I am using .NET 6 and posting via Swagger or Postman to this method:
I changed this to what Alberto suggested below.
[HttpPost]
[Route("Test")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromBody] OrderData data)
{
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
   {
      
       var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
       // You can then process the body data here.
       Console.WriteLine(body);//this shows the full base64
       var result =  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OrderData>(body);
       Console.WriteLine(result.DocumentData);//this does not show full base 64
      
   }
    return Ok();
}

public class OrderData
{
    public string DocumentData { get; set; }
}

Posting JSON to this endpoint the base64 that is in there is large and causes the bottom part to be cutoff.
The data is over 10mb in size.
I have tried to change it to a string and dynamic type instead of the object with the same results.

What JsonSerializer have you configured to be used here?

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject after I get the body and read it to end

You comment does not fit you code in the question. The code tells me you let the system do the model mapping. Your comment show something when you do it yourself. What is correct?  JsonConvert looks like something from NewtonSoft Json.Net. It has no relevant restrictions on the size of a value. Have you checked if the string you send there that its valid and complete beforehand? I could imagine problems in the string that ends in not being serialized complete like when it contains a 0 byte that is then interpreted as string end somewhere in the Serializer.

This was changed to match what was below. Appreciate the information.

Is there any configuration related to the request size in the server? And is there any related error message?

Looks like there are several approaches you can try here or combine them.
From .NET side:
You can decorate the method with:
[RequestSizeLimit(104857600)] // 100MB for example

Although, the default size is around 30mb, check reference.
Also, I would recommend use stream reader as another option instead of deserializing it all, example:
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        // You can then process the body data here.
        return Ok();
    }
}

If that does not work, the issue might be from the tool you are using, in this case Postman, sometimes it can timeout or behave oddly with large payloads.
You can try to modify the request timeout, go to settings > General > Request Timeout in milliseconds or you can visit this page for a better guide: how to set request timeout in postman.
I hope this helps.

Ok I added both of those to the post method and decorated with the requestsizelimit and still receive a truncated base64. I do not understand why it is truncating it. FYI, if i use a really long string and pass it in json it still cuts it off.

Also, the request timeout in postman is already set to 0 in which I understand it is supposed to be unlimited correct?

Ok, it actually is pulling the data in to the method but when I deserialize it it truncates it.

Yes, 0 in postman is default so it should be fine. Maybe you want to share a link where we can see an example of the data or code? Seems to be a issue in how it is deserializing it.
